# ElasticSearch with n word separation and regular expression (with Tire gem)

Tags: ruby, regex, elasticsearch, tire

I am using ElasticSearch (with the Tire gem). I have the following query which will match `escaped cat`, `escaped black cat`, etc.

I was wondering, is it possible to ask ElasticSearch to search with the following criteria:

1. "escaped [exactly 0 or 1 word] cat" ie) `escaped \w{0,1} cat`
2. "escaped [n words] cat" ie) `escaped \w{n} cat`
3. "escaped [Regular expression here] cat" ie) `escaped (big|black|white) cat`

Current searching query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "\"escaped ? cat\"",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "\"escaped ? cat\"",
            "default_operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "flt_field": {
            "content": {
              "like_text": "\"escaped ? cat\""
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mlt_field": {
            "content": {
              "like_text": "\"escaped ? cat\""
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible using Elasticsearch's [regexp query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/regexp-query/).

```
{
    "regexp":{
        "name.first": "s.*y"
    }
}
```

There's also a [regexp filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/regexp-filter/)